# Using MySQL PASSWORD function in our app

Tags: mysql, hash, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

In MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) for `PASSWORD` function:

> The PASSWORD() function is used by the authentication system in MySQL
>   Server; you should not use it in your own applications. For that
>   purpose, consider MD5() or SHA1() instead.

Why we shouldn't use this function in our application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few reasons I can think of

1. It's a fast hash (SHA1 I believe) which isn't a good property for password hashes.
2. They might change what hash it uses in a future version of MySQL, breaking your application.  They've already done this once, hence the OLD_PASSWORD() function.
3. It doesn't naturally use a salt (although you could use a salt with it if you wanted to by appending it to the password before calling the PASSWORD function)
4. It's non-standard SQL, so if you ever need to port your app to another platform you'll need to come up with a replacement